# Unable to access OS X SMB share FROM a Win10 (domain) PC, not accepting passwords

Tags: network, file-sharing, smb

[I've setup a File Sharing on my Mac Mini](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/share-mac-files-with-windows-users-mchlp1657/mac) (Late 2014, OS X Yosemite v10.10.5). When I try to access it from a Win10 (v1507) PC with File Explorer address of `\\1.2.3.4` (IP of mac) it prompts for a username/password however will no accept any!? [I've created a new user 'Sharing' for this purpose](https://www.howtogeek.com/313230/how-to-set-up-network-file-sharing-on-macos-without-sharing-your-username-and-password/) so I am confident of the password. I suspect it has something to do with my Win10 PC being part of an Active Directory. I've tried username in these formats without success: sharing, sharing@1.2.3.4, 1.2.3.4/sharing
[image: AppleFileSharing]
[image: AppleFileSharingTypes]
[image: AppleSMB Share Win10 Prompt]

[My question is ALMOST a duplicate of this one, except they were using a Android tablet whereas I am using a Win10 domain-joined PC](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114662/os-x-samba-file-sharing-continuously-asks-for-password). I tried it anyways (paste following into Terminal: `echo "[default]" >> ~/Library/Preferences/nsmb.conf; echo "smb_neg=smb1_only" >> ~/Library/Preferences/nsmb.conf`), but it hasn't helped :(

Comment: A long shot, but maybe see if this helps - https://superuser.com/questions/888923/specific-windows-7-to-mac-smb-share-rejected-others-ok-troubleshooting

Comment: Have you tried this: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210423

Comment: Since the PC is part of a domain, you must specify the user as `COMPUTERNAME\sharing`. And this is the tricky part: Windows will probably not be able to resolve the Mac's hostname because it's not a member of the domain, but you could try using your Mac's **NetBIOS name** like this `NETBIOSNAME\sharing`. To find out the NetBIOS name of your Mac, either launch Terminal and run `defaults read /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server NetBIOSName` or open System Preferences>Network>Advanced>Network and check it there.

Comment: @Tetsujin I am about to try that, a little worried it'll cause other issues on this domain PC. Robert that guide is connecting a MAC to a Windows/SMB share, I am trying to do the opposite. jaume good to point out, but that makes no difference. I am thinking it has something to do with the SMB version authentication